# Pandas iterating over arrays with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded a CSV with 3 columns: a Timestamp, a userID and a campaignID. 
Each user has >1 campaignID with a timestamp. The raw data looks as follows:

```
                   date    user_id           ad_campaign
0      2018-01-10 0:21:09  151312395      Search - Special
1      2018-01-10 0:21:19  151312395    Display - Branding
2      2018-01-10 0:21:32  151312395    Display - Branding
3      2018-01-10 0:21:09  151312395      Search - Special
4      2018-01-10 0:21:19  151312395    Display - Branding
5      2018-01-10 0:21:32  151312395    Display - Branding
6     2018-01-30 19:18:37  158490415               Display
7     2018-01-30 19:19:03  158490415               Display
8      2018-01-31 1:36:12  158490415              Branding
```

My goal is to map the order of the different campaignIDs for each user, in order to analyze which campaign often comes first, second, last and so forth. 
I have removed the duplicates, have ordered the timestamp, grouped by userID and put the campaignID per user in an array. 
Now, I want to have a loop that iterates over each user's array and then assigns each campaign per user a 'place', like 1st, 2nd,3d (the step after that will be to attribute scores to each campaign according to where in the userjourney they are, to make my goal more clear). This is the code I have now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


columnnames = ['date','user_id', 'ad_campaign']
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\L\Desktop\Data.csv' , 
    sep='\t',names = columnnames, usecols=[0,1,4],  
    parse_dates=True)

df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id','date', 'ad_campaign'])
df=df.set_index('date').sort_index()
df=(df.groupby(['user_id'])['ad_campaign'].apply(list)) 

print(df)
```

The data now looks as follows:

```
user_id
151312395    [Search - Special, Display - Branding, Display...
158490415    [Display, Display, Branding, Display, Display,...
176204518    [Display, Display, Display, Display, Pathfinde...
182053572    [Branding, Branding, Branding, Display]
```

I have tried looping with iterrows, itertuples, itervalues and so forth but I think I am missing something about the way I have stored this data, because I keep getting different errors. What kind of loop should I be using?

Comment: Mind pasting the first 5-10 rows of `C:\Users\L\Desktop\Attribution Data 4.csv` as text in your question?

Comment: Sure, this okay? (The actual CSV data has a lot of columns, this is what I read in)

Comment: Thanks, super helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do you one better. Let's ditch the intermediate column-of-lists representation (it's really hard to work with and offers zero performance benefit). Instead, label each campaign its unique sequence number (done using `groupby` + `cumcount`), and then you can do something simple like a grouped `mean` by campaign.

```
df = df.sort_values(by='date')

(df.groupby(['user_id'], sort=False)
   .cumcount()
   .groupby(df.ad_campaign)
   .mean()
   .sort_values(ascending=True)
)

ad_campaign
Display               0.5
Search - Special      0.5
Branding              2.0
Display - Branding    3.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using also min() and max() instead of mean(), which also works. But can you help me understand how to interpretate the three? I am just trying to understand because my next step is a more complicated model of attributing 40% to the first campaign in each user sequence, 40% to the last campaign in that user sequence and 20% dividing over the campaigns in the middle (trying out different marketing attribution models).

Comment: @LailaVanMents I'm not convinced min or max make more sense in this context than mean, which is basically averaging the campaign positions in time for each user ID. Based on your explanation, you may instead consider performing a weighted average, which may be a little more involved. You may open a new question for that, but it is possible.